# Fetch data from back end to front end after getting it in router from database

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mern, reducers

I am building a mern expo app login and signin page. When clicking the signin button it should login but I couldn't get the data from the backend though i already made the find query inside the router express. I believe my code will help you understand better.

routeSignIn.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/User");

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then((user) => {
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json("Email or password is incorrect");
    } else {
      const foundUser = res.json(user);
    }
  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const url = "mongodb://localhost/my-project1";
mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });

const con = mongoose.connection;

app.use(express.json());

//Router
 const routeSignIn = require("../route/routeSignIn");
 app.use("/getUser", routeSignIn);

con.on("open", () => {
  console.log("Database is connected...");
});

const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
  const { address, port } = server.address();
  console.log(`Server started. Listening at http://${address}:${port}`);
});
```

This is where the problem is, I couldn't fetch it from the router

SignIn.js

```
  const loginHandle = (email, password) => {
    axios
       //The address here is my laptop IP address, because i wanted to link my mern server with expo server
      .get("http://192.168.29.7:3000/getUser") 
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res) {
          Alert.alert("Invalid User, Username or password is incorrect.");
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error fetching data : ", err);
      });

    if (data.email.length == 0 || data.password.length == 0) {
      Alert.alert("Email or password field cannot be empty");
    }
  };
```

App.js

```
const authContext = useMemo(
    () => ({
      signIn: async (email) => {
        const userToken = String(foundUser);
        try {
          await AsyncStorage.setItem("userToken", userToken);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log("SignIn error", err);
        }
        dispatch({ type: "LOGIN", email: email, token: userToken });
      },
    }),
    []
  );
```

As you can see above what i wanted to do is after routing(in routeSignIn.js) with the specific user i wanted to fetch that data(from signIn.js) and pass that data into App.js to dispatch it. Note that the reducers function is in the same file(App.js) as that of the the dispatch.

Comment: Where do you use `authContext`

Comment: in the same file where the auth context is initialized  , i.e App.js

Answer (score 1):

I think there are several issues that I can detect with the way you are posting and retrieving data from your DB.

First of all, you are using `axios.get` function instead of `axios.post` and you are posting it to a URL that simply doesn't exist (`"http://192.168.29.7:3000/getUser"`). You will instead need to use someting like `"/getUser/login"`. Also define your const as `loginHandle = userData` and in your `userData` define email as `user.email` and password as `user.password`.

In the server-side you might want to use port 3000 or 5000 and see which one works the best as sometimes you might need to run your server on port 5000.

In your `routeSignIn.js` file, use `router.post("/login"` instead so you can make sure you are routing to the correct URL.

I am not quite sure about your `app.js` so not gonna comment on it.

Hopefully this, to some extent, fixes your problem but I would recommend following [this](https://github.com/rishipr/mern-auth) as much as possible and when you are comfortable with NodeJS and React, then customise the code.

Comment: Hello Kamran, really appreciate for your help...I believe something is not right about the way I implement the code. Can you please take a look at my [source code](https://github.com/Sang-Tonsing/my-project1) and see if you can help me come up with a slight modification/different/alternate way of letting the user sign in if the credentials is valid.

Comment: I would recommend using the link above and follow their approach until you fully understand it and then you can customise the code to suit your need. However, as it is only a login request (all done in the back-end) you can pretty much use the same code.